# Proportions question

Tags: arithmetic

I do not know how to approach this qn properly ..

Qn -  6 workers working 8 Hours per day were tasked to complete a building project in 5 days . After working for 3 days , 2 of the workers were sick and could not report to work for the next few days . Assuming that all the workers work at the same rate , how many additional hours per day must each of the remaining workers work for the remaining 2 days in order to complete the project on schedule ?

My workings till I got stuck -

6 workers - 8x5= 40hours - 1 project

6 workers - 8x3= 24 h - 24/40 of  1 project

Comment: How many hours of work the project need in total? Clearly $6\times 8\times 5$. Ask yourself how many hours are still needed after 3 days and how can you distribute them in the remaining two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each worker would be aiming for $8 \times 5 = 40$ hours over the project. This means that the project would have a total of $6 \times 40 = 240$ hours of work to complete.

After $3$ days, the workers would have completed a total of $(8 \times 6) \times 3 = 144$ hours towards completing the project. So, there are $96$ hours left to do, but for the last $2$ days, only 4 of the workers will be contributing. So, each builder will have to work $96/4 = 24$ hours, which means $12$ hours a day each.

Since each builder was already aiming to complete 8 hours a day, this means that they will work an additional $12-8 = 4$ hours per day.